# XCode 5 vs XCode 4 - where are the options

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

My old Mac had 10.6 and XCode 4.2 (which was the latest for that system). There I was able to select "Other C Flags" and "Other Link Flags" and set them appropriately.

Now I got a Mac which has 10.8. I install XCode 5.1.1 and I couldn't find those settings anymore.

Are they being split up? Renamed? If that's the case how do I set them up?

I know its not actually a programming question, but its tightly related and also I asked to post XCode related stuff here on SO from "Ask Different".

Thank you in advance and hopefully this question is OK to ask here. If not please point me to the proper place on any SO site and I will gladly move it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is indeed a programming question, since it has to do with Xcode.

If you open your project in Xcode, select the target (which is the app you ultimately build) and then click on "Build Settings".

There should be a search field into which you can type in the search term "Other".

Here's a screenshot of what I see when I do this in Xcode 7:

[image: Use the search term "other" when viewing target settings]

I've circled "Other Linker Flags" and "Other C Flags" for you.  You should see the same results in Xcode 5 & 6.